# Awk? Append an incremental number to each line containing a symbol

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file of sequences.

```
>seqA
lakjdsflakjsdlkjals;dkjfal;kdjsfl;aksdjf;lakjsdfl;kjalsdkjf
alsdkjfalskdjf;alsdfj;alkdjsf;lakjsdf;lkajsd
>seqB
fjal;kdjsfla;kdjsflkajdslkjfaghal;sdkjg
>seqC
a;lksdjl;akjsdg;lkjsdfl;kajdsl;kgj;alkdjsg;lkajsdgl
lsdkfja;lksdjf;lakdjsf;lkajsdfl;kjal;sdkfjal;skdjak
sdkjfal;ksdjflk;ahdglkahsdl;kghalk
```

I'd like to add an increasing incremental number after each ">"

For example:

Output file:

```
>1seqA
lakjdsflakjsdlkjals;dkjfal;kdjsfl;aksdjf;lakjsdfl;kjalsdkjf
alsdkjfalskdjf;alsdfj;alkdjsf;lakjsdf;lkajsd
>2seqB
fjal;kdjsfla;kdjsflkajdslkjfaghal;sdkjg
>3seqC
a;lksdjl;akjsdg;lkjsdfl;kajdsl;kgj;alkdjsg;lkajsdgl
lsdkfja;lksdjf;lakdjsf;lkajsdfl;kjal;sdkfjal;skdjak
sdkjfal;ksdjflk;ahdglkahsdl;kghalk
```

So far after scouring the internet I've tried:

```
awk -F "i=1" '{if (/>/){print $0i++} else print}'
```

and it didn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
awk '/>/{$0 = ">" ++i substr($0, 2)} 1'
```

For example:

```
$ awk '/>/{$0 = ">" ++i substr($0, 2)} 1' file
>1seqA
lakjdsflakjsdlkjals;dkjfal;kdjsfl;aksdjf;lakjsdfl;kjalsdkjf
alsdkjfalskdjf;alsdfj;alkdjsf;lakjsdf;lkajsd
>2seqB
fjal;kdjsfla;kdjsflkajdslkjfaghal;sdkjg
>3seqC
a;lksdjl;akjsdg;lkjsdfl;kajdsl;kgj;alkdjsg;lkajsdgl
lsdkfja;lksdjf;lakdjsf;lkajsdfl;kjal;sdkfjal;skdjak
sdkjfal;ksdjflk;ahdglkahsdl;kghalk
```

#### How it works

- `/>/{$0 = ">" ++i substr($0, 2)}`

  This selects lines that contain `>`.  For those lines, we replace the line `$0` with `>` followed by `++i` (which is the value of the variable `i` after it has been incremented) followed by the current line starting at its second character.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for taking the time to explain it. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
awk '/^>/{sub(/^>/,">"++i)}1' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation:

```
awk -F'>' -v OFS='>' 'NF == 2 {$2 = ++count $2} 1' file
```

That uses ">" as the field separator, and uses the number of fields as the condition.